# XML and ASCII characters, box drawling

Tags: xml, ascii

Xml2rfc supports figures that could be shown with using of the next structure:

```
  <figure align="center">
              <artwork align="center">
                <![CDATA[
 ┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
            ]]>
              </artwork>
            </figure>
```

I tried the ASCII for box drawling and faced the issue, the characters are not displayed properly..

For example, instead the figure:
 ┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
in the xml2rfc we see:

```
 a&#148;&#143;a&#148;&#129;a&#148;&#129;a&#148;&#129;a&#148;&#129;a&#148;&#129;a&#148;&#129;a&#148;&#129;a&#148;&#129;a&#148;&#129;a&#148;&#129;a&#148;&#129;a&#148;&#129;a&#148;&#129;a&#148;&#129;a&#148;&#129
```

I suppose that ASCII characters are not treated properly. Are there any ways to specify in the structure that we use specific ASCII characters such that to make them been treated properly by xml2rfc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at [an ASCII table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Character_set) you'll note, that there are no box drawing symbols. All those symbols are in other character sets.

You need to take care, what character set you're editing your XML in, what you claim it is to XML parsers (the `<?xml charset="..."?>` declaration) and what any intermediate party might do with it.

The result that you pasted looks like scrambled `latin1`, that some tool tried to convert into something it knows (like interpreting some bytes you entered in a wrong encoding).

Make sure, that all your tools use UTF-8, then you have the best chances to get all characters through unscrambled. Note, that [XML2RFC](https://xml2rfc.tools.ietf.org/rfc7749.html#special.unicode.code.points) specifically says,

> Although the current RFC format does not allow non-ASCII Unicode characters[...]

so that's still no guarantee, that everyone is on the right side of the millennium with regards to non-ASCII characters.